# Count occurrences in a text line

Tags: bash, count, uniq

Is there any way to count how often a value occurs in a line?. My input is a tab delimited `.txt` file. It looks something like this (but with thousands of lines):

```
  #N/A  14 13   #N/A    15 13   #N/A    14 13   13 15   14 13   15 14   14 15
    24 26   #N/A    24 22   #N/A    24 26   #N/A    24 26   24 22   24 22   24 26
    45 43   45 43   #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    43 45   45 43   #N/A    47 45   45 43
```

I would like an output like this or similar.

```
 #N/A(3)  14 13(3)  15 13(1)  13 15(1)  15 14(1)  14 15 (1)
 24 26(4)  #N/A(3)  24 22(3)   
 45 45(4)  #N/A(4)  43 45(1)  47 45(1)
```

Comment: could you format your question correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl solution:

```
perl -laF'/\t/' -ne '
    chomp; my %h;
    $h{$_}++ for @F;
    print join "\t", map "$_ ($h{$_})", keys %h
' < input
```

- `-a` splits each line on `-F` (`\t` means tab) into the @F array
- `-l` adds newlines to prints
- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `chomp` removes the final newline
- %h is a hash table, the keys are the members of @F, the values are the counts

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F'  +' -v OFS='  ' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i!="")a[$i]++; 
        for(k in a) printf "%s", k"("a[k]")" OFS; delete a; print ""}' file

#N/A(3)  14 13(3)  13 15(1)  15 13(1)  14 15(1)  15 14(1)
#N/A(3)  24 22(3)  24 26(4)
#N/A(4)  43 45(1)  45 43(4)  47 45(1)
```

Comment: is the spacing the same as what you posted?  As a field separator it's looking for at least two spaces.

Comment: OK. I see the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is a tab. I fix it with a \t. Thanks